# Sum of numerators of different fractions in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, fractions, lcm

I have an array of cells that contain all numerators (A2:A500) and an array of cells that contain all denominators (B2:B500) think of them as a fraction.

Is there a way to put them to the smallest common fraction and sum them up in one line? I can do it with the use of another column with multiplied numerators but I struggle to make it a one liner. How can something like this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get easily an overflow if the `LCM` of column B is too high. Anyway, this formula will get you the *numerator* of the sum fraction:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A500/B2:B500)*LCM(B2:B500)
```

Obviously the *denominator* is `=LCM(B2:B500)`

p.s.: I assumed you wanted to have a `Fraction` as a result. If you want just the resulting number, Garry's answer is the straightforward way to go.

Comment: Many thanks this worked for me, I didn't know that you can put "/" into sumproduct

Answer (score 0):

An example for three cells:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3/B1:B3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thought the OP wants to keep a fraction form as result. Will delete my answer if that's not the case.

Comment: @Garry it will depend if OP wants a fraction. Not that clear :)

Answer (score 0):

And you may calculate the GCD(numerator,denominator)
to obtain the reduced fraction.